# R, labels on bar chart in the wrong order

Tags: r, bar-chart

I'm attempting to add labels to a barchart. The data is the output of `prop.table(xtabs())` function and is wrapped into manipulate function so I believe it limits me to base plotting. Original data had factors ordered, i.e. I need XXL at the bottom,  XL next... etc.

The question is about `text()` function:

1. Labels are not in the correct order, I tried to transpose the matrix and now some are correct and some are not.
2. Other: can't seem to align labels with columns.

```
dataF <- matrix(
  c(0.0287081340, 0.2044657097, 0.6306220096, 0.1259968102, 0.0095693780, 0.0006379585, 0.0087591241, 0.1149635036,
  0.5737226277, 0.2525547445, 0.0500000000, 0.0000000000, 0.0130584192, 0.0439862543, 0.5374570447, 0.3415807560,
  0.0628865979, 0.0010309278, 0.0029620853, 0.0112559242, 0.2434834123, 0.4751184834, 0.2606635071, 0.0065165877,
  0.0007883327, 0.0193141506, 0.3133622389, 0.4355538037, 0.2230981474, 0.0078833268, 0.0079646018, 0.0146017699,
  0.2641592920, 0.4539823009, 0.2522123894, 0.0070796460, 0.0003047851, 0.0033526364, 0.0850350503, 0.4102407802,
  0.4775982932, 0.0234684547),nrow=6,ncol=7)

dimnames(dataF) <- list(c("XXL","XL","Large","Medium","Small","X-Small"),
                        c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7"))

xx <- barplot(dataF, col=1:nrow(dataF), xlim=c(0, ncol(dataF) + 5), width = 0.85)
legend("topright", rev(rownames(dataF)), fill = rev(1:nrow(dataF)))
text(x = 1:7, y = t(dataF), label = round(t(dataF)*100), pos = 3, cex = 1, col = "black")
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Num1's XXL is 0.0287 and XL is 0.2044, so XXL's y-position is 0.0287 / 2 and XL's is 0.0287 + 0.2044 / 2
2. X-position aren't 1:7. When you don't give arguments `width`and/or `space`, they are 0.7, 1.9, 3.1, and so on. I think it would be better not to set them to keep x-coordinates.

Here is my example;

```
### calculatiton of y-position
library(dplyr); library(reshape2)
d <- melt(dataF) %>% group_by(Var2) %>% mutate(pos = cumsum(value) - 0.5 * value)

### draw
xx <- barplot(dataF, col=1:nrow(dataF), xlim=c(0, 11)) # keep legend space by xlim (11 doesn't mean much)
legend("topright", rev(rownames(dataF)), fill = rev(1:nrow(dataF)))

with(subset(d, value > 0.04),    # don't write small values
     text(x = 0.7 + 1.2 * (Var2 - 1), y = pos, label = round(value * 100), cex = 1, col = "black"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @cuttlefish44 . One question: where do the values 0.7, 1.9, 3.1... come from? Are they some kind of preset intervals?

Comment: @Konstantin Mingoulin; They come from default value of `barplot()`'s argument, `width = 1` and `space = 0.2` (par width; absolute value is 1 * 0.2 = 0.2). So first bar's left = 0.2, middle = left+0.5, right = left+1. Next bar's value = first bar's + 1.2, and so on.

Comment: and I noticed I said one wrong thing. `xlim` doesn't related. You can use it instead of `par(mar)` to keep space (I edited).